# Añadir a la ultima iteración de un foreach una clase - Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade

estoy iterando un foreach en mi vista para obtener unos datos, pero puedo añadir que al último resultado le añada una clase de css??

```
@foreach ($mensajes as $item)
  <li data-horizontal-timeline='{"date": "{{ $item->fecha }}"}'>
   {{ $item->mensaje }}
  </li>
@endforeach
```

A la última iteración quiero añadirle esto: `class="selected"` ¿Es posible?

Comment: De ser posible claro que lo es, pero como sabrás necesitamos que nos muestres algo que hayas intentado y de ahi partir

Comment: Hola @BetaM si tienes razón no publique lo que estaba probando, yo lo intentaba hacer con `$key` pero no me funcionaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la variable `$loop` que ofrece [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable).

```
@if ($loop->last)
    La ultima iteración
@endif
```

Comment: Gracias @L.Flor por tu ayuda, funciona perfecto!